# Create gradient with 4 colors and small intersections?

Tags: ios, swift, cagradientlayer

There are a lot of questions here about how to create multicolor gradients, but what I am struggling is to create gradient where gradient areas are small. For example i want to have 4 colors on view, and I want 3 intersections between colors to have small gradients.

```
    gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = gradientFrame
    let locations = [Float](arrayLiteral: 0.3, 0.35, 0.8, 0.85)
    gradientLayer.locations = locations.map { NSNumber(value: $0) }
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,
                            UIColor.orange.cgColor,
                            UIColor.green.cgColor,
                            UIColor.gray.cgColor]
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

I get nice gradient between red and orange, and green and gray. But gradient between orange and green is much larger and doesn't look right.

[image]

I have not been able to fix this. Any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use green *twice* in the sequence of colors. Red orange green green gray. Now you can have a big solid green in the middle and thin transitions on either side of it. Example:

```
    let locations = [Float](arrayLiteral: 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.8, 0.85)
    gradientLayer.locations = locations.map { NSNumber(value: $0) }
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,
                            UIColor.orange.cgColor,
                            UIColor.green.cgColor,
                            UIColor.green.cgColor,
                            UIColor.gray.cgColor]
```

[image]

That's the general principle; just tweak it however you like.

Comment: Can be used more than twice to get proper proportions :)

Comment: @えるまる Correct, that is what the last sentence of my answer means.